# Workerman closes suddnly after send message

Tags: php, websocket

I am using `workerman` PHP library to create WebSocket server.

```
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Workerman\Worker;

// Create a Websocket server
$ws_worker = new Worker("websocket://0.0.0.0:8047");

// 4 processes
$ws_worker->count = 4;

// Emitted when new connection come
$ws_worker->onConnect = function($connection)
{
    echo "New connection\n";
};

// Emitted when data received
$ws_worker->onMessage = function($connection, $data)
{
    var_dump($data);

    // Send hello $data
    $connection->send('hello ' . $data);
};

// Emitted when connection closed
$ws_worker->onClose = function($connection)
{
    echo "Connection closed\n";
};

// Run worker
Worker::runAll();
```

everything works fine. So I use this class to send message web socket server:

```
// https://github.com/Textalk/websocket-php

$client = new Client('ws://127.0.0.1:8047/');
$client->send('test !');
```

Sometimes output this error:

```
// Validate response.
if (!preg_match('#Sec-WebSocket-Accept:\s(.*)$#mUi', $response, $matches)) {
    $address = $scheme . '://' . $host . $path_with_query;
        throw new ConnectionException(
         "Connection to '{$address}' failed: Server sent invalid upgrade response:\n"
         . $response
    );
}
```

If restart server it works again ... but every time after send connection is closes. I can't understand why connection closes.

```
PHP 7.2.0 (cli) (built: Nov 28 2017 23:48:49) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```